# BTYD package in R dc.SplitUpElogForRepeatTrans too slow

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the BTYD package in R to model customer lifetime value, but the step to split up the data for repeat transactions seem to be taking way too long.

I have a data frame with less than half a million rows, and I have substituted customer_id's, which used to be long strings, into just integers, and it is still taking very long.

Here is the exact readout of str(df)

```
'data.frame':   466617 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ date : Date, format: "2015-04-05" "2015-04-05" ...
 $ sales: int  55 69 2 52 39 62 10 20 25 53 ...
 $ cust : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

when I run dc.SplitUpElogForRepeatTrans(df), this seem to go on forever.

For people who have used this package before, is half a million lines considered too much for this package? What are some ways to speed up the process or get around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem as I have several million rows. I found that the function `dc.SplitUpElogForRepeatTrans` was very slow, so I switched out the loop for [some `data.table` magic](https://github.com/321k/BTYD/blob/master/R/dc.R). Huge difference in speed.